# How to pass two parameters to custom event handler in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, antd

I am using Ant design and they have a component called `Switch`, `Switch` have a custom event handler

```js
import "./styles.css";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Switch } from "antd";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(true);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // e is a boolean variable, true or false
    console.log(e);
    setStatus(e);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Switch checked={status} onChange={handleChange}></Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and I have so much of question about that kind of syntax

1. Does

```js
onChange={handleChange}
```

is equivalent with

```js
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
```

2. If for some reason, I can only write

```js
onChange={handleChange}
```

how can I pass the **real** event handler to `handleChange` to do some `stopPropagation`, some thing likes

```js
const handleChange = (e, reale) => {
    reale.stopPropagation()
    setStatus(e);
  };
```

Simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-jones-scgqo) to understand what I said.

Comment: 1. Yes they are same. 2. You can simply write as what you have. Is there any issue with that?

Comment: @cjmling uhm, i  don't know how to pass real event handle to handleChange function, how to do it?

Comment: You don't need to. You can simply do `onChange={handleChange}`, You should have reale variable as event handler. https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-bird-5m11n?file=/src/App.js.  Do you want to pass different event handler? If so, then do as Tanisq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does
> `onChange={handleChange}`
> is equivalent with
> `onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}`

They're equivalent if and only if the function receives one argument. But for ant design switches, the onChange actually passes in two parameters: the new value, and the event object. So if you want to create a new function and then call handleChange in that function, you'll probably want to pass both parameters through:

```
onChange={(value, e) => handleChange(value, e)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write thing something like

```js
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, reale)}
```